# Flip coordinates as if they were a grid

Tags: python, grid, coordinates

I have been at it for a long time but can't finish what I'm trying to do. I am trying to find a way to flip coordinates based on a list of objects and a list of their coordinates.

```
objects = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
grid_placement = [(0,0), (32, 0), (64, 0), (0, -32), (0, -64)]
```

I want to get the flipped axis coordinates of where they are

So the ideal flipped Y output would essentially be:

```
placement = [(0, -64), (32, -64), (64, -64), (0, -32), (0, 0)]
```

And the ideal flipped X output would be:

```
placement = [(64, 0), (32, -64), (0,0), (64, -32), (64, -64)]
```

So essentially if something is in the top right, it would be on the top left after flipping on X. Their index positions would remain the same in the list, but with the altered coordinates.

The code I have cobbled together works just fine for the Y axis, but I cannot get the X axis working. My brain is a little fried from messing with this for a few hours, any outside advice would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code (messy)

```
    gridSize = 32
    if axis == "x":
        columns = defaultdict(dict)

        for gridOffset in self.offsetList:
            row = gridOffset[1] // gridSize
            col = gridOffset[0] // gridSize
            columns[col][gridOffset] = row

        new_order = []
        order = list(reversed(list(columns.keys())))
        for col in order:
            for offset in self.offsetList:
                if offset in columns[col]:
                    new_order.append((col * gridSize, columns[col][offset] * gridSize))

    elif axis == "y":
        rows = defaultdict(dict)

        for gridOffset in self.offsetList:
            row = gridOffset[1] // gridSize
            col = gridOffset[0] // gridSize
            rows[row][gridOffset] = col

        new_order = []
        order = list(reversed(list(rows.keys())))
        for offset in self.offsetList:
            for row in order:
                if offset in rows[row]:
                    new_order.append((rows[row][offset] * gridSize, row * -gridSize))

    self.offsetList = new_order
```

Answer (score 0):

Your examples suggest that you want to swap object coordinates rather than "flip" them.  To actually flip on a Cartesian plane you would need a pivot point.  If that point is (0,0) flipping would amount to inverting the sign of the X or Y coordinate you want to flip.

On the other hand if you want to swap coordinates between objects, use zip:

```
# vertical swap
grid_placement = [(F[0],B[1]) for F,B in zip(grid_placement, grid_placement[::-1])

# horizontal swap
grid_placement = [(F[1],B[0]) for F,B in zip(grid_placement, grid_placement[::-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking on what I needed to do more clearly.